# Twitter composer is not broadcast the status of tweet

Tags: java, android, twitter, kotlin

I have implemented the Twitter composer in my app and it is successfully tweeting to my account but it doesn't broadcast the status of the tweet like success or failed. 
Below is my code:

```
  TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(activity).text(shareContent)
  builder.show();
```

Broadcast Reciever code:

```
public class MyTwitterResultReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (TweetUploadService.UPLOAD_SUCCESS.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Tweet uploaded successfully with Tweet ID : " + tweetId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TweetUploadService.UPLOAD_FAILURE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to uploaded tweet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TweetUploadService.TWEET_COMPOSE_CANCEL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "User cancelled Tweet compose..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

And i have added this reciever in my manifest file like below:

```
   <receiver android:name=".twitter.MyTwitterResultReciver"
              android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_SUCCESS"/>
            <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.UPLOAD_FAILURE"/>
            <action android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.TWEET_COMPOSE_CANCEL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: This is correct, the Composer does not provide a success or failure. If you need to check, you’ll have to manually use the Twitter API to confirm whether a Tweet was posted.